# Multiple databases (multiple DbContexts) in one transaction using TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have got two DbContexts(One Model-first and the other one is code first) which connects to two different databases in MSSQL.
Now when you call SaveChanges from any class, it writes data to both the databases at the same time using TransactionScope class. Code looks like below.

```
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (Schema1Entities db1 = new Schema1Entities())
            {
                db1.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (Schema2Entities db2 = new Schema2Entities())
            {
                db2.SaveChanges();
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

The problem raises during runtime. it is saying that

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> Inner-exception message - {"The partner transaction manager has
>   disabled its support for remote/network transactions. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8004D025)"}

Turned on MSDTC, and no firewall is blocking the MSDTC.
Need help immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple database in one transaction in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468245/multiple-database-in-one-transaction-in-entity-framework)

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130767/the-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions

Comment: referred these already but no use. AllSparl, David_L

Comment: If you don't use the `TransactionScope`, it saves the changed without any issue? Just a shot in the dark: did you try placing both `SaveChanges` in the same using block? (Both `using` lines next to each other).

Comment: Thats awesome Andrew. Your dark shot worked. many thanks

Comment: @zzzziiiirrrrkkkkkkkk, I just realized you never accepted my answer, LOL.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments under the question, this solved the issue:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (Schema1Entities db1 = new Schema1Entities())
    using (Schema2Entities db2 = new Schema2Entities())
    {
        db1.SaveChanges();
        db2.SaveChanges();
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```